# cannot pass state of the button (true of false) to function in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

*In ViewController is declared*

```
var secondActive :Bool = true


@IBAction func swichState(sender: UIButton) 

{

    secondActive = !secondActive;  

    print("Boolean set to  + \(self.secondActive.boolValue)")  

    // return secondActive.boolValue();    

}
```

*In calculator engine class ViewController instantiated:*

```
var viewC: ViewController?

case "sin":

if operandStack.count >= 1 

        {                                
            if (self.viewC!.secondActive == true) {

                return sin(self.operandStack.removeLast() * M_PI/180)

            }

            else {

                return asin(self.operandStack.removeLast() * M_PI/180)

            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you get instance of `self.viewC`?

Comment: The local variable `var viewC: ViewController?` is `nil`. You need a reference to the real instance of `ViewController`

Comment: `viewC` is hardly nil. If it was then `viewC!` would cause a runtime exception. I'd agree with the tow if you were using `self.viewC.secondActive`. However, `viewC`might refer to a different instance of ViewController. Can you share how and where you instantiate `vewC`? And double check that `viewC` in the calculator engine and `self` within `ViewController` are actually the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using @IBAction, I assume your viewController is made on a storyboard or xib, and therefore, you shouldn't be instantiating it. I think Hermann Klecker's comment is correct, that you're making a new instance of your view controller if you are in fact instantiating it there. You would have to pass the existing instance into your engine.

You might reconsider having your switch state set on the view controller, and you should certainly reconsider having your engine own a reference to the view controller.